# AngularJS not binding object properties to template/html element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Fairly new to angularJS, watching Todd Motto's paid tutorials, and I dont know why but my objects properties wont show up on the page.

```
function AddCurrentJobs($scope){
$scope.jobinfo = [{
    title: 'Building Shed',
    description: 'I need helping building a shed'
},
{
    title: 'Jello',
    description: 'Test 123'
}];

}

angular
 .module("app")
 .controller("AddCurrentJobs", AddCurrentJobs);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AddCurrentJobs">
{{jobinfo}}
</div>
```

Result in div element:  [{"title":"Building Shed","description":"I need helping building a shed"},{"title":"Jello","description":"Test 123"}]

Now if change it to jobinfo.title, it will return with nothing in the element.
I tried using the repeat directive but that doesnt work either.
No errors in the console.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: jobinfo[0].title (its an array that holds objects)

Comment: does your repeat attempt look like `<span ng-repeat="job in jobinfo">{{ job.title}}</span>` ?

Comment: @LukeGaskell Yes that works as Sajeetharan has also said but my ng-repeat does the same thing.    `<div ng-controller="AddCurrentJobs as jobs">
 {{jobinfo[0].title}}
 <div ng-repeat="job in jobs">
  <p>{{job.jobinfo}}</p>
 </div>
</div>`

Comment: @taki It looked like the comment I posted under yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Sajeetharan's answers, you can use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to display data from each object in your list of job info. `ng-repeat` are similar to a `foreach` loop, so the syntax is, "[object] in [list]", and you can then access the properties on that object as you normally would.

```
<div ng-controller="AddCurrentJobs">
  <div ng-repeat="job in jobinfo">
    <h1>{{job.title}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your Array like object in HTML, you can access specific element using its index as,

```
<div ng-controller="AddCurrentJobs">
  <h1>{{jobinfo[0].title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I should of made the question about using the ng-repeat but this does solve just choosing a specific value in the array.

Comment: yeah if its array you should be using ng-repeat. mark if this helped